# Creating Wix contact with WixHive Rest APi

Tags: php, rest, velo

everybody.

I'm developing dashboard app for wix.com sitebuilder.

I use PHP for that. I try to work with wix contacts using WixHive and Rest API

Here is documentation about this:

```
http://dev.wix.com/docs/wixhive/contacts
http://dev.wix.com/docs/wixhive/using-the-rest-api
http://dev.wix.com/docs/wixhive/rest-api
```

Unfortunatelly, wix have no php SDK. I create my own class based on this unofficial sdk:

```
https://github.com/ransom1538/wix_php_sdk
```

Get single contact and contacts list works like a charm.

But reconcileContact doesn't work.

Return suche error:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-Seen-By: sputnik4.aus_dsp
Date: Tue, 01 Sep 2015 08:15:00 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 83
Server: sputnik4.aus

{"errorCode":401,"message":"Bad authentication credentials.","wixErrorCode":-23004}
```

I implemented signature using this tutorial:

```
http://dev.wix.com/docs/wixhive/using-the-rest-api#signature
```

I checked it with this tool:

```
http://dev.wix.com/docs/infrastructure/signature-tool
```

and I see that signatures match.

My request looks like that:

```
URI: 

https://openapi.wix.com/v1/contacts?version=2.0.0&application-id=13ffc79d-ceb8-df76-74e0-3de5b0f29b2d&instance-id=8c4c0505-370a-451b-bd9b-6667f955c26e&timestamp=2015-09-01T12%3A11%3A41.477Z&signature=lkwqWrVFRCAhtpgGjqCn6v3TgUnakiIFKjMog41J-zQ 

Method: POST 

POST Data: {"emails":{"tag":"work","email":"karen_meep@wix.com","emailStatus":"recurring"}}
```

Sources:

```
https://gist.github.com/antonshell/e92cb9cc57e7c8555d3a
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the request header `version=2.0.0` to `version=1.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

When you are submitting json data in POST method. You should have content-type header in post request. So your curl_request method will be

```
public function curl_request($method, $uri, $data = '')
{
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1);
   if ($data != '') {
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)));
   } else {
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
   }
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 45);
   if ('POST' == $method)
   {
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
   }
   else if ('PUT' == $method)
   {
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
   }
   else if('GET' != $method)
   {
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
   }
   $response = curl_exec($ch);
   $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
   $body = substr($response, $header_size);
   return $body;
```

}